# Browser asks for two certificates instead of one

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, ssl, proxy, certificate

I have two apps with different urls:

```
1.asp.net mvc on IIS -> ex. www.backend.com
2.nginx Angular in Cloud -> ex. www.frontend.com
```

Both services asks for Certificate.

```
In backend, it's set on IIS.
In frontend, it's in nginx configuration.
```

User wants to run page, first nginx is loading and asks for Certificate.
Then frontend wants data and calls backend. Backend asks again for Certificate.
N service = N popups
It's not good for user experience to get this popup each time (**user can have a few certificates**, if there is one then perhaps browser would pick up automatically).

Question, how could I solve it? I want to select one Cert to validate everything.
I cannot remove Certs.

```
1)Can frontend populate this Cert somehow? There are different urls but it's the same Cert
2)Any proxy/Load Balancer could work? If yes, could I please for example?
```

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The browser does not know that the domains have any relation with each other and that the same certificate should be used - and there is no way for the application to tell the browser.

If you want to keep the approach with two domain facing the users and both requiring a certificate, then you will need to live with this problem as it is know. You might want to put everything on a single domain with some TLS terminating reverse proxy (or load balancer) in front - but then only this reverse proxy will see the client certificate and the servers behind the reverse proxy must trust the proxy to have checked the client certificate properly.

Similar you might put the backend behind the TLS terminating frontend server, in which case the backend must trust the frontend to have checked the client certificate.